# Сборка SDL исходников для NDK

Tags: cmake, sdl2

Через Cmake пытаюсь собрать исходники SDL2, чтобы получить `.so` библиотеку, но при сборке получаю ошибки вида `SDL_stdinc.h:307:49: error: unknown type name 'wchar_t'`

```
cmake  -DSDL_SHARED=ON -DSDL_STATIC=OFF -DANDROID_NDK=C:/AndroidNDK -DANDROID_ABI="armeabi-v7a" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:/AndroidNDK/Android.[toolchain][1].cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "Unix Makefiles" ..
```

make

В чем моя ошибка, как собрать so для Android с помощью cmake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

не стал заморачиваться и собрал `libSDL2.lib`через `ndk`'шный `make`

```
ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=. APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=Android.mk APP_PLATFORM=android-16
```